# Using kivy.garden.gauge in screenmanager

Tags: python-2.7, screen, kivy

I'm working on a display project that will have two screens each showing gauges and I can't get the kivy garden gauge code to work with a screenmanager.
It works fine as a standalone app, but I can't find any instructions to help me incorporate it into a screen. The kivy calculator example works fine inside a screenmanager screen, but that's only .kv code, my GaugeApp class won't run any way I've tried when placed in a screenmanager screen.

Here's the working standalone code:

```
from kivy.garden.gauge import Gauge
from kivy.app import App

dirflag = 1

value = 50

from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

class GaugeApp(App):
increasing = NumericProperty(1)
begin = NumericProperty(50)
begin2 = NumericProperty(25)
begin3 = NumericProperty(75)
step = NumericProperty(1)

def build(self):
    box = FloatLayout(orientation='horizontal', padding=5)
    self.gauge = Gauge(value=50, size_gauge=156, size_text=25, pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .2})
    self.gauge2 = Gauge(value=10, size_gauge=226, size_text=25, pos_hint={'x': .22, 'y': .3})
    self.gauge3 = Gauge(value=10, size_gauge=156, size_text=25, pos_hint={'x': .02, 'y': .2})
    box.add_widget(self.gauge)
    box.add_widget(self.gauge2)
    box.add_widget(self.gauge3)

    Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *t: self.gauge_increment(), 0.1)
    return box

def gauge_increment(self):



    begin = self.begin
    begin += self.step * self.increasing
    if begin > 0 and begin < 100:
        self.gauge.value = begin
    else:
        self.increasing *= -1
    self.begin = begin

    begin2 = self.begin2
    begin2 += self.step * self.increasing
    if begin2 > 0 and begin2 < 100:
        self.gauge2.value = begin2
    else:
        self.increasing *= -1
    self.begin2 = begin2
# Main program

GaugeApp().run()
```

Any help to incorporate this into a screen layout will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's long ago but if You still have the problem:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/I0_xBF3DlAM/9M2ppsWnngQJ

I copied the "garden.gauge" folder in c:\.kivy\garden\ giving it a new name. Then making the changes to **init**.py as described in the link. Now it works.